# Toolbar: changing menu items and background and items color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-animation, android-toolbar

In my application I want the Toolbar to behave like in most Google applications.

In those apps, when you select items from a list, the Toolbar changes it's menu items, and changes it's color and StatusBar color. Everything is followed by an animation.

[image: Toolbar color change]

I would like to know the best way of doing that. Maybe there is an official API, or a good library?

Here are my thoughts:

1. Having two sets of menu items and manually adding/removing or showing/hiding them, and changing Toolbar color with something like [Property Animator](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)
2. Having two Toolbars at the same position, and replacing them when needed. (You can see on the .gif image that Toolbar's Title's margin changes, so it is most likely that there are two Toolbars)
3. ?

Comment: its called actionmode not a toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called `action mode`. Generally used to show extra options for a specific operation.

have a look at this link [Creating Contextual Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu).

Comment: Didn't know about that. Thank you!